useSWR refreshInterval not working as expected
This is how I am using useSWRInfinite to get notifications for my Nextjs Web App. I want to refresh the data every 30s or something. But I dont seem to see any network call in the network tab.
const { data, error, isLoading, isValidating, size, setSize } =
    useSWRInfinite(getKey, fetcher, {
      revalidateFirstPage: false,
      revalidateOnMount: true,
      // dedupingInterval: 5000,
      refreshInterval: 7000,
      refreshWhenHidden: true,
    });

But It is only doing a network call for the first time. But it is not refreshing again after the specified interval again and again as expected.
Thi is how I used it
const NotificationBox = () => {

  const { data, error, isLoading, isValidating, size, setSize } =
    useSWRInfinite(getKey, fetcher, {
      revalidateFirstPage: false,
      revalidateOnMount: true,
      // dedupingInterval: 5000,
      refreshInterval: 7000,
      refreshWhenHidden: true,
    });

 return (<div> ... </div>)

